# Average of values with same key in a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I am learning about nested dictionaries in python. Here I am trying to calculate the average of values that have the same key, this is my dictionary,

```
avg = {'AKL': [{'Fhr': '19:30', 'Dhr': '39:25', 'Thr': '141:00'}, 
               {'Fhr': '58:10', 'Dhr': '130:35', 'Thr': '414:25'}, 
               {'Fhr': '7:30', 'Dhr': '18:25', 'Thr': '30:40'}, 
               {'Fhr': '7:00', 'Dhr': '14:15', 'Thr': '26:30'}], 
       'CHC': [{'Fhr': '33:10', 'Dhr': '62:20', 'Thr': '157:20'}, 
               {'Fhr': '51:55', 'Dhr': '101:40', 'Thr': '263:55'}]}
```

I have tried to calculate the averages like this:

```
result_dict = dict([(k, sum(average_dict[k].items())) for k, v in average_dict.items()])
```

This is the error I'm getting currently,

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I want the result like this,

```
{'AKL': {'Avg Fhr': 28.23, 'Avg Dhr': 187.85, 'Avg Thr': 195.21},
 'CHC': {'Avg Fhr': 42.32, 'Avg Dhr': 81.8, 'Avg Thr': 210.37}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: result_dict = dict([(k, sum(average_dict[k].items())) for k, v in average_dict.items()])
I have tried to calculate like this

Comment: +1 for @Chris' question; esp. because this is a learning question, I'd expect the best help we can provide is a guiding direction, rather than a "here's a full working code solution" (and SO isn't a code-writing service anyway)

Comment: @prishi23 please edit the code in your question instead of a comment, if you can. Also let us know what the result you got in your code is, and if it didn't work what error message(s) you got instead.

Comment: your `avg` dictionary is not a valid dictionary.  are those supposed to be decimal numbers instead of what looks like times?

Comment: You need another for-loop to access the list

Comment: @Chris no they are time values and I need the average of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def time2float(s):
    a,b = s.split(':')
    return int(a)+int(b)/60

out = {}
for k,l in avg.items(): 
    d = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
    for e in l:
        for k2,v2 in e.items():
            d[k2] += time2float(v2)
    out[k] = {k:round(v/len(l),2) for k,v in d.items()}
```

output:

```
{'AKL': {'Fhr': 23.04, 'Dhr': 50.67, 'Thr': 153.15},
 'CHC': {'Fhr': 42.54, 'Dhr': 82.0, 'Thr': 210.62}}
```

input:

```
avg = {'AKL': [{'Fhr': '19:30', 'Dhr': '39:25', 'Thr': '141:00'}, 
               {'Fhr': '58:10', 'Dhr': '130:35', 'Thr': '414:25'}, 
               {'Fhr': '7:30', 'Dhr': '18:25', 'Thr': '30:40'}, 
               {'Fhr': '7:00', 'Dhr': '14:15', 'Thr': '26:30'}], 
       'CHC': [{'Fhr': '33:10', 'Dhr': '62:20', 'Thr': '157:20'}, 
               {'Fhr': '51:55', 'Dhr': '101:40', 'Thr': '263:55'}]}
```

##### output as time strings:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def time2float(s):
    a,b = s.split(':')
    return int(a)+int(b)/60

def float2time(i):
    a,b = divmod(i, 1)
    return f'{int(a)}:{round(b*60):02}'

out = {}
for k,l in avg.items(): 
    d = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
    for e in l:
        for k2,v2 in e.items():
            d[k2] += time2float(v2)
    out[k] = {k:float2time(v/len(l)) for k,v in d.items()}
```

output:

```
{'AKL': {'Fhr': '23:02', 'Dhr': '50:40', 'Thr': '153:09'},
 'CHC': {'Fhr': '42:32', 'Dhr': '82:00', 'Thr': '210:38'}}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with the values. Currently it is hours, and I want to convert it to float
(ex. 19:30 -> 19.30)

Comment: @prishi23 then maybe you should have mentioned that in the beginning, so those are strings?? `19:30` is not a valid python object. And what it the mean of `['19:30', '19:30', '20:30']`? You cannot simply convert to float ;)

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that all sub `dict`s have the same amount and same keys. You can use `statistics.mean` and a dict comprehension:

```
from statistics import mean

avg = {'AKL': [{'Fhr': 19.30, 'Dhr': 39.25, 'Thr': 141.00}, {'Fhr': 58.10, 'Dhr': 130.35, 'Thr': 414.25}, {'Fhr': 7.30, 'Dhr': 18.25, 'Thr': 30.40}, {'Fhr': 7.00, 'Dhr': 14.15, 'Thr': 26.30}], 
       'CHC': [{'Fhr': 33.10, 'Dhr': 62.20, 'Thr': 157.20}, {'Fhr': 51.55, 'Dhr': 101.40, 'Thr': 263.55}]}

result_dict = {key: dict(zip(vals[0], map(mean, zip(*map(dict.values, vals)))))
               for key, vals in avg.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'AKL': {'Fhr': 22.925, 'Dhr': 50.5, 'Thr': 152.9875}, 'CHC': {'Fhr': 42.325, 'Dhr': 81.80000000000001, 'Thr': 210.375}}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the order of the keys is not consistent or if you have missing keys in some occurrences of the sub-dictionaries ;)

Comment: I know, I'm annoying :p

Comment: Lol, as per OP's example assumptions were made

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at your `sum(avg[k].items())` bit -- that will need replaced with a list comprehension of `list_elem.items()`. Can you figure out why/how?